# Select id of ul inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a variable that selects the id of the ul with `class="cd-faq-group"`.

The ul is inside a div with `id="items"` and `class="cd-faq-items"`.

Right now I have the following code inside a js function:

However, this doesn't seem to be working.

```
function searchBar() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    var ids = $('div.items').find("ul.cd-faq-group").attr("id");
}
```

And yes, I am a noob at coding in general.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: **ul is inside a div with id="items"** So you should use `$('div#items')` instead

Comment: Maurits - Your code will work to find the ID of the **first** element matching the criteria. (It's the same as `$("div.items ul.cd-faq-group").attr("id")` which is the same as `$("div.items ul.cd-faq-group").first().attr("id")`.)

Comment: @Mohammad - I think the idea is to **get** the ID of the matching element, rather than find an element using an ID you already know.

Comment: I am using AJAX to download data from our JSON, parse it, and build the HTML structure using template literals. Does it help providing you with all of the javascript code and html div class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one `ul` in `div` you can use:

```
function searchBar() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    var ids = $("#items").find("ul.cd-faq-group").attr("id");
}
```

**ELSE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  searchBar();
});


function searchBar() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  var uls = $("#items").find("ul.cd-faq-group");
  $.each(uls, function(i, item) {
    var id = item.id;
    console.log(id);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items" class="cd-faq-items">
  <ul id="1" class="cd-faq-group">
  </ul>
  <ul id="2" class="cd-faq-group">
  </ul>
  <ul id="3" class="cd-faq-group">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have multiple ul's

Comment: Thank you, I got it working by using your function and creating an array out of the id's

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
var ids = $('div#items').find('ul.cd-faq-group').attr('id');
console.log(ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items"  class="cd-faq-items">
<ul id="1" class="cd-faq-group">

</ul>
</div>
```

Multiple ul

```js
$("div#items ul").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items"  class="cd-faq-items">
<ul id="1" class="cd-faq-group">1</ul>
<ul id="2" class="cd-faq-group">2</ul>
<ul id="3" class="cd-faq-group">3</ul>
</div>
```